# Map range to array in rust (nested)

Tags: matrix, rust, vector, range, mapping

The following rust code calculates the product matrix * vector as an array on the stack and displays it:

```
fn main () {
    let matrix: [[f64;3];3] = [
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
        [ -1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
        [ 1.0, 0.0, -1.0 ],
    ];
    let vector: [f64;3] = [
        3.0,
        -2.0,
        1.0,
    ];
    let range = [ 0, 1, 2 ];
    let result: [f64;3] = range.map(
        |i| range.map(
            |j| matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
        ).iter().sum()
    );
    println!( "{:?}", result );
}
```

In principle this is fine, but I find the use of an array of indices awkward. How could I use a range instead for the indices like this:

```rust
    let range = 0..3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct an array elementwise using a function, use [`from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/fn.from_fn.html):

```rust
let result: [f64; 3] = std::array::from_fn(
    |i| (0..3).map(
        |j| matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
    ).sum()
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8494ce43032e4eea8049d22de04cf60f)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not very functional, but sometimes simple `for` loops work perfectly well:

```
let mut result = [0.0; 3];
for i in 0..3 {
    for j in 0..3 {
        result[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j];
    }
}
```

But if you want to stay (more) functional (state *is* being mutated here), you can use `iter_mut` + `enumerate` to get the index from the iteration itself, instead of a separate range array:

```
let mut result = [0.0; 3];
result.iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, r)| {
    *r = matrix[i].iter().zip(vector).map(|(a, b)| a * b).sum();
});
```